# Remove and Insert in a circular queue

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures, queue

In college the professor has asked us to devise an algorithm to implement the circular queue. We have to write algorithms for the 'remove()' and 'insert()' functions. This is what I came up with after hours of thinking.

```
Declarations: q = circular queue structure that contains 3 elements 
                --> x[MAX] = array of MAX integers
                --> rear = logical pointer used for inserting elements at that particular index
                --> front = logical pointer used for deleting elements at that particular index
Predefined functions:
                --> incr (int y) : special function to set y to 0 once it contains MAX else do y++
                --> decr (int y) : special function to set y to MAX if it contains 0 else do y--

Preconditions : At the initial time of defining the structure set rear and front both at 0

Algorithm REMOVE(q): Returns an int
1.  set a <- q.x[q.front]
2.  incr (q.front) 
3.  if q.front >= q.rear 
    1.  decr (q.front)
    2.  print "Queue Empty"
    else
    1. return a

Algorithm INSERT(q,a) : Returns nothing
1.  incr (q.rear)
2.  if q.rear = q.front
    1.  decr (q.rear)
    2.  print "Queue Full"
    else
    1.  set q.x[q.rear] <- a
```

This algorithm uses the fact that 'front' never overtakes 'rear'. Thus on increasing 'front' if 'front = rear' means queue is empty. And on increasing 'rear' if 'rear = front' means queue is full.

But when I showed this to my Professor he said that this is not the solution.

Is this logic incorrect? If so, what is the flaw in this algorithm?
Also if possible please suggest improvements.

(PS: The reason I have not Googled for solutions is because I want to implement this myself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your setup fails if the first operation after initialization of your queue is a REMOVE request. the reason for this is that you first increment the front index and then check whether is equals the rear index to detect whether the queue is empty or full. however, after initialization both indexes are already equal while the queue is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. If I change the condition to front>= rear in the step 3 of the REMOVE algorithm it gets taken care of.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should consider to Check for Equality of Indexes first in your insert/REMOVE operations to avoid the reversal of incr/decr calls if the queue is empty/full

Comment: Sure that would make the algorithm more efficient. But the reason why I have written it that way is to make the logic I am using more self-explanatory.

Comment: i feel it clearly more Natural to Test preconditions first, performing any dependent actions thereafter. I'd even consider this a kind of a pattern and expect other Code to behave similarly. Ymmv and imho, of course.

Comment: Sure. I respect your opinion. And will keep it in mind while writing further algorithms.